# How to catch spanner transaction errors

Tags: google-cloud-spanner, google-cloud-spanner-emulator

I am currently working on spanner emulator for my local development and eventually will use actual instances. I am trying to run a bad SQL query expecting to catch and throw an error message for the users.

When I run the below query using cloud, I see `HTTPError`

`gcloud spanner databases execute-sql --project=local-gcp-project testdb --instance=Emulator --sql='SELECT SingerId, AlbumId, AlbumTitle FROM Albums'`

```
(gcloud.spanner.databases.execute-sql) HTTPError 400: {"error":"Table not found: Albums [at 1:43]\nSELECT SingerId, AlbumId, AlbumTitle FROM Albums\n^","code":3,"message":"Table not found: Albums [at 1:43]\nSELECT SingerId, AlbumId, AlbumTitle FROM Albums\n^"}
```

When I use the python client library to run the same query I do not see any errors and I see `inside try` getting printed always.

```
spanner_client = spanner.Client()
instance = spanner_client.instance("Emulator")
database = instance.database("testdb")

def execute_transaction(transaction):
   query = "SELECT SingerId, AlbumId, AlbumTitle FROM Albums"
   transaction.execute_sql(sql=query)
try:
  database.run_in_transaction(execute_transaction)
  print("inside try")
except GoogleAPICallError as e:
  print("inside e")
```

Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2):

`execute_sql` returns a `StreamedResultSet`, which gets evaluated lazily. You won't see the error until you iterate through the result. Changing your example to read the result set into a list:

```py
from google.cloud import spanner_v1 as spanner
from google.api_core.exceptions import GoogleAPICallError

spanner_client = spanner.Client()
instance = spanner_client.instance("Emulator")
database = instance.database("testdb")

def execute_transaction(transaction):
    query = "SELECT SingerId, AlbumId, AlbumTitle FROM Albums"
    return list(transaction.execute_sql(sql=query))

try:
    database.run_in_transaction(execute_transaction)
    print("inside try")  # never gets here
except GoogleAPICallError as ex:
    print(ex)  # 400 Table not found: Albums...
```

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. I have a bunch of SQL queries that need to get executed. Looks like I need to iterate through the result for each one of them. That will work for me but I am wondering if there is a setting on the database that I can change to change this behavior.

Comment: Nope, the Spanner client libraries return an iterator by design. If you want to fetch all the results in `execute_transaction` just wrap it in a `list` as in the example.